# Is mysql insertion possible without the field names

Tags: mysql

To save time and space is it possible to insert into a mysql db without the use of the field names as shown below:

With the fields

```
INSERT INTO `wp_realty_listingsdb` (`listingsdb_id`,`user_id`,`class_id)
values
    (1,1,1);
```

Without the fields

```
INSERT INTO `wp_realty_listingsdb` values(1,1,1);
```

Comment: Possible but not recommended as it would break as soon as you alter the table structure

Comment: Use this URL, which will gives you all possible ways to insert data in mysql table. `https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp`

Comment: You could test this for yourself as quickly as ask us. Buy yes, as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly omit the field names from an insert statement as you have done here:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_realty_listingsdb`
VALUES
    (1,1,1);
```

However, the caviat is that MySQL will assume that your data is intended for the `listingsdb_id`, `user_id`, and `class_id` columns, in that order.  This would also assume that these columns also respectively appear in the first, second, and third positions of the table.

In general, it is probably best practice to always list the column names, for many reasons.  It makes it clear what you are actually doing.  Also, nameless inserts could break down the road if the table structure changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding values for all the columns of the table, you do not need to specify the column names in the SQL query. However, make sure the order of the values is in the same order as the columns in the table.

Otherwise, if you are inserting to specific columns of table then you must enter the column names.

Comment: This doesn't deserve a downvote and I have countered it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ! Its Possible To Insert Like This

```
INSERT INTO `wp_realty_listingsdb` values(1,1,1);
```

Comment: The reason i asked in te first place as i have spent extensive time testing this and have not gotten it to work. .after listening to the comments that it should work i tried again to no avail.. 
Keeps saying this: 
#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
So I tested extensively using hte 111 for first 3 items then added the full fields like (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)  and nothing works.. Has anyone physically tested this.. since i have tried every way but loose with no work.

Comment: This will be massive time saver and work to only deal with data and not have to touch the jillion bytes  for field names and this must run daily dealing with 50,000 plus field name..so simple if it will take raw data..

Comment: yes before posting i have tried the query it works without providing field names, and for the error of Column count, you might be missing some fields in query.

Answer (score 0):

Insert `NULL` into the auto-increment field.

I recommend that unless this is a hack script, you use field names.  The rationale is that your code will **break** if you ever add a field to the table or change their order.

Instead, be explicit with field names, and it will go much better in the future.

Comment: For the commenter that says test it yourself and not waste our time.. I did but must have done something wrong as it did not work.. is the reason i asked.. Second it is my own personal program and noone will have access to it and it will drastically speed up and use way less bytes of space to do that... since i no longer have to move 200+ field names in the insert statement... and that is huge.. so will try again as that will massively simplify my pgm...so thank you to those who willingly helped me here.. i did not mean to burden the one person...

Comment: Thanks for all yur help it is working well now... apparently my testing was on just the first 3 fields and that is fine when the names are used.. but just like the book sez... if you will use no names then you must insert every dang field in the db... which i did and it works great now.. Thanks for all your help .... so many correct answers.. how in the world do I pick the best one.. when your answer works it works. SOLVED!